# Pass Express req and res data to client using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I am using ReactJS with client-side routing and attempting to implement a Facebook login using Passport. Everything is fine except I am unsure how to pass the req.user I generate to my React component, as I am not using Handlebars or Jade. Is this possible?

UPDATE

Here is the current code I am using:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'), function(req, res){
  if (req.user){
    res.send(req.user);
  }
});

app.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
      successRedirect : '/'
}));
```

What I don't know how to do is access the req.user in my client-side React component (I am storing authentication and user info via a session with Flux), as any documentation shows loading it up through a Jade or Handlebars template, neither of which I am using. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I added my Express routes and some extra information so you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: You need to make an ajax call from flux to a route defined in your express app that returns req.user and whatever else you want as JSON. Your ajax callback parses the json and extracts the data into your react app.

Comment: were you able to login successfully ? if so can u share the code even i am stuck in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you want to expose the whole req.user to the client? The idea of using sessions is to remove that data from the client completely, since the client is always assumed as an insecure host. Therefore, the mapping between the user data and the session is done via the sessionId of the cookies install on the client.

In the past, I needed the client to know its username after login, but nothing else. I resolved that problem by putting a cookie in the client with that value. Would this be a viable approach for you? That is, selecting the data that needs to be known by the client (instead of passing the entire user object) and putting it within a cookie itself?